# I don't want to track a subfolder available in all folders?

Tags: git, gitignore, django-migrations

There is a subfolder migrations which is in all apps. I want to ignore this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open .gitignore and insert this in a new line

> migrations

This will ignore all `migrations`.

or to ignore only those inside your app's directories:

> /app-*/migrations

Assuming all your app directories are prefixed with `app-`. You could adjust them in anyway on how your directories are structured.

[Link to gitignore Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Note: Make sure to remove from your repository first what you'll be adding to your gitignore.

Comment: Added to the answer. That could also work but it may include unintended migrations outside of his apps.